# Как удалить одну запись из объекта

Tags: node.js

```
let obj = {};

s[12] = {
    'baseAsset': 12,
    'quoteAsset': 1
}

s[49] = {
    'baseAsset': 42,
    'quoteAsset': 543
}
```

Как удалить запись s[12]?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Comment: Да, все работает. Спасибо.